# Where should I store private files in an R package?

Tags: r

I'm developing an R package with an XLSX file that serves as a template for a function that exports a report.

I currently store it under `inst/` but I don't think this is best as the user should have no access to that file.

I know I could store it privately as an object, but I'd like to know if it is possible to store it privately as a file that's loaded when the package user executes their code. This would make the file more easily update-able and the current codebase would require less restructuring.

Comment: What do you mean by “private”? Secret? If you distribute your package, *no* part of it is secret, and this cannot be changed.

Comment: It seems a bit strange to have an XLSX file that has to be private, since a template is unlikely to contain information that users shouldn't see. If you just don't want users to tamper with it, then you could write your code in such a way that the report will only be generated if the XLSX file matches an md5 hash that you generate and hard-code into your package. This would stop users from making changes to the XLSX. Or you could make the package access a fixed online copy of the xlsx each time. As @KonradRudolph says, you can't distribute a package and have a part of it being private.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. This is not a security concern though. It wouldn't really matter if the user accesses the file. But there's no reason for them to do it as it's a template with no relevant data. So I wanted to know what is the best practice in this case.

Comment: Fair point. In that case the best practice is just to put it into `inst/` and to trust the user not to rummage around in this. In other words: R has no real separation between public and private file data in packages.

Comment: Don't worry, speaking for myself, you'll never find a user that doesn't mess with what they're not supposed to.

Comment: Oh okay. No need to make any changes then. Thanks for your answers!